# Struggling to get the currentTime of an audio element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to control an audio element to use in my custom player, but for some reason I cannot get the currentTime of and duration. I've tried numerous things like:

```
var player = $("#player");
player.ontimeupdate = function () {
myFunction()
};
alert(player.currentTime);
```

Which alerts "undefined". So why isn't this working? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: #player refers to which element?

Comment: @NikhilBatra The '<audio>' element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this:

```
var player = $("#player")[0];
var player = $("#player").get(0);
```

You are applying on jQuery object! Not the correct HTML element.